# Chrome packaged app and Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to have a Chrome packaged app for Android also include a module built with the Android NDK, and then communicate between the app's javascript and the native NDK module?

Because PNaCl is not yet available for Android, I'm looking for another way to bring C code to that platform also, in place of the PNaCl module that I have for the other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can install cordova plugins using the `cca` tool, and cordova plugins can bundle ndk components.  However, there is no utility/project that I know of to help you get started build ing the android ndk -> cordova android -> cordova js.

I don't think it should be hard, especially if you've done cordova/phonegap plugin development before.